# Where should I subtract 1 when generating random numbers as a list index?

Tags: python, list, random

When I want a random item of a list, I normally do:

```
import random
random.randint(0, len(array)-1)
```

(and then put that in as the index for the list)

However, I was wondering if it was more efficient / better practise to do the following:

```
import random
random.randint(1, len(array)) -1
```

Does it make any difference to execution time, or is better practise, in general, to use one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`random.randrange(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) which works like range:

```
import random
random.randrange(len(array))  # OR  random.randrange(0, len(array))
```

or even better, use more readable [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) which return random element out of the sequence:

```
random.choice(array)
```

Comment: Why is `choice` better? Is it just more elegant?

Answer (score 2):

for this `choice` exists: try

```
random.choice(your_list)     # returns a random element from the list
```

Answer (score 0):

Running some tests (a loop, 100,000 long generating using each technique):

Method 1 (`random.randint(1,len(lst)-1)`)

```
         14.73
         14.81
         15.04
         14.71
Average: 14.8225
```

Method 2 (`random.randint(1,len(lst))-1`)

```
         14.94
         14.91
         14.85
         14.85
Average: 14.8875
```

So they essentially take exactly the same amount of time - the differences are almost certainly random - linking in to the other activity on my computer.

Comment: `random.randint(0,len(lst))-1)` -> `random.randint(1,len(lst))-1)`